# Cloud pages take 5 minutes to update

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage

Why is it, when I update, save and publish a landing page, that the changes are not immediately available when you request the page?

The changes to a landing page seem to go live with 5 minutes interval, despite the option at time of publishing a landing page saying 'publish immediately'.

Am I having too high expectations?

Comment: I develop CloudPages using the method described in the post above.  I agree, it really is a pain to paste/publish/repeat.

Comment: I saw that post and thought I'd ask more specifically about the delay between publishing and seeing the changes live. I thought maybe I missed something in that there is a developer mode / debug mode or some temporary way of disabling this caching etc. before settling on something that works :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route that fetches CloudPage messages is cached for performance reasons.

Comment: well that sucks when you try to develop something. There should be some way to turn this off when in development mode.

Comment: You're not wrong, but too many people abuse options like this.